# Как вывести несколько имён из list используя function?

Tags: python, функции

Скажем, у меня есть список имён:

```
names = ['Jon', 'Sarah', 'Ed', 'Mia', 'Kendall', 'Derek', 'Andy', 'Kevin']
```

Как можно создать function, чтобы оно случайно вывело скажем, пять имён? Можно чтобы и повторялись одни и те же имена, это не критично.

Я без function вроде сделал это так:

```
import random
names = ['Jon', 'Sarah', 'Ed', 'Mia', 'Kendall', 'Derek', 'Andy', 'Kevin']
chosennames = random.sample(names, 5)
print(chosennames)
```

Оно выдает что-то вроде:

```
['Sarah', 'Kendall', 'Derek', 'Andy', 'Kevin']
```

А мне нужно используя *def*, и чтобы результат выдавало как **Sarah, Kendall, Derek, Andy, Kevin**, без каких-либо символов лишних.

Прошу помочь. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам возвращает список, если хотите строку, используйте `join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
def func(names): 
   chosennames = ', '.join(random.sample(names, 5))
   return chosennames

names = ['Jon', 'Sarah', 'Ed', 'Mia', 'Kendall', 'Derek', 'Andy', 'Kevin']
print(func(names))
```

Comment: Yernar, спасибо за ответ. 
Поможете дальше расширить код? Нужно вывести:
Group 1: 'пять имён из списка'
Group 2: 'пять имён из списка'
Group 3: 'пять имён из списка'

Чтобы каждый Groups был на новой строке 

Пробую так, не получается:

def func(names):
    group1 = "Group 1: ".join(random.sample(names, 5))
    group2 = "Group 2: ".join(random.sample(names, 5))
    group3 = "Group 3: ".join(random.sample(names, 5))

    return group1, group2, group3

print(func(names))

Выдаёт всё на одной строке, не сортировано

Comment: @RavOcean, Давайте))

Comment: Обновил коммент)

Comment: @RavOcean, https://repl.it/@YernarSadybekov/DazzlingMemorableSmalltalk

Comment: Yernar, есть Telegram? Было бы хорошо там связаться, знаниями поделиться

Comment: @RavOcean, мой ник в телеге `SSYernar`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
names = ['Jon', 'Sarah', 'Ed', 'Mia', 'Kendall', 'Derek', 'Andy', 'Kevin']
def get_names(my_names):
  chosennames = random.sample(my_names, 5)
  print(*chosennames) # или так для Python3 
  return " ".join(chosennames) # или так сразу для Python 2 и 3
print get_names(names)
```